# Blank Auth Dialog Window in Outlook React Addin

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I have tried using [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) and [office-js-helpers](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers) for authenticating users in my Outlook Addin React app and both of them create pop-ups for auth but they are both blank screens. Both methods return the following error

> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
>   The document will render with garbled text in some browser
>   configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
>   US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be
>   declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order
>   mark as an encoding signature.

At first I thought this may be because my Auth domain was not listed in my manifest with an `AppDomain` tag, but I have since added it and reinstalled my add-in with no success.

Here are the two versions I have tried:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://foobar.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000', {height: 30, width: 20});
```

and

```
authenticator.endpoints.add('Cognito', {
  redirectUrl: 'https://localhost:3000',
  baseUrl:'https://foobar.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2',
  authorizeUrl: '/authorize',
  responseType: 'token',
  tokenUrl: '/token',
  state: false,
  nonce: false,
  scope: 'openid',
  extraQueryParameters:null,
  clientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
});
//for the default Microsoft endpoint
authenticator
    .authenticate('Cognito')
    .then(function (token) { return console.log('good') })
    .catch(function(err)
    {
      OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log();
      console.log("CATCH ERROR")
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
    });
```

I don't particularly care which method I use, I just need one of them to work.

Answer (score 0):

The URL that you pass to `displayDialogAsync` should be in the same domain as the add-in, which in your case is localhost:3000. However, that URL can be a blank page that immediately redirects to a login page. For more, see [Auth with the Office Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api).